# Helm3 release history is only showing the last 10 revisions

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

There is probably a very straightforward answer, but I'm having trouble with it.

Helm is only showing the last 10 revisions if the `--max` flag value provided is greater than 10. Does helm only store the last 10 revisions?

```
$ helm history airflow --max 256 -o table
REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION DESCRIPTION
76          Thu Oct  1 12:52:51 2020    pending-upgrade airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Preparing upgrade
77          Thu Oct  1 16:01:55 2020    superseded      airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
78          Thu Oct  1 16:02:52 2020    superseded      airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
79          Thu Oct  1 16:32:53 2020    superseded      airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
80          Thu Oct  1 16:52:51 2020    superseded      airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
81          Fri Oct  2 11:06:38 2020    superseded      airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
82          Fri Oct  2 11:08:56 2020    superseded      airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
83          Fri Oct  2 11:16:41 2020    superseded      airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
84          Fri Oct  2 11:25:19 2020    superseded      airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
85          Fri Oct  2 12:07:29 2020    deployed        airflow-7.9.0   1.10.12     Upgrade complete
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default saved history len is 10 (starting Helm3). The flag is only available in `helm upgrade` (dunno why they didn't add to `install` too):

```
$ helm upgrade --help  | grep history-max
      --history-max int              limit the maximum number of revisions saved per release. Use 0 for no limit (default 10)
```

Comment: Strange that it’s not part of the helm history documentation. But I appreciate it!

Comment: helm3 release rush - it was much awaited

Comment: Offending PR: https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/6421 from more than 2 years ago.
10 was set as the default to align with k8s's ReplicaSet default of keeping 10 old RSes.

Comment: This command doesn't work for me. my helm version is 3.7.1

Comment: Try checking in the manual https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/